# Idle in transaction on system query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

My database got partially stuck because of the one query, which status was 'idle in transaction'

```
SELECT typname FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE oid = $1
```

As soon as it was terminated via `pg_terminate_backend` the database recovered and started act properly.

1. What could be the reason of that query? I never used this query in my system intensionally.
2. How to prevent this query to be *idle in transaction*?

Database is used by Hibernate 4.3.x via datasource, `io.vertx.ext.jdbc` and nodejs's pg module

Comment: This is primary client side issue. The query is ok, problem is some where on client side - unhandled exception, ...

Comment: If it happens again, check `pg_stat_activity` to see what client it came from. You might have to use `netstat` to match up the client port with the application process/thread the connection came from. Then look at the application with a debugger, etc, to see why it isn't progressing with the transaction. That query alone shouldn't make the database "stuck"; if the session was idle in transaction the query had finished anyway and that was just the most recent query. More likely it was locks held by the transaction. Next time look at `pg_locks` too.

Comment: Oh, you might be able to find out what application it was by looking at the application error logs. When you terminated the PostgreSQL backend the client will've received an error, and may have saved that to its own logs.